# To evaluate limit of sequence $\left(\left( 1 + \frac1n \right) \left( 1 + \frac2n \right)\cdots\left( 1 + \frac nn \right) \right)^{1/n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, radicals

How do I evaluate the limit of the following sequence
$$a_n  = \left(\left( 1 + \frac1n \right) \left( 1 + \frac2n \right)\cdots\left( 1 + \frac nn \right) \right)^{1/n}$$

I tried to take log and then using cauchy $1^{st}$ theorem of limits but I coudn't do it.

Could someone kindly help?

Comment: @ajotatxe power raised is 1/n

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/997763/ (This is the geometric mean of the numbers in the interval $[1,2]$.)

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99324/how-to-prove-that-lim-frac1n-sqrtnn1n2-2n-frac4e) (see and other [posts linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/99324)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rewrite $\displaystyle a_n = \prod\limits_{k=1}^{n} \left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)^{1/n} $

Since, [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} b_n^{1/n} = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287932/convergence-of-ratio-test-implies-convergence-of-the-root-test) (that is if the limit exists)

We may write:

$\displaystyle \begin{align} \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n =\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} \left(1+\frac{k}{n+1}\right)}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n} \left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)} &= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} (n+k+1)}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n} (n+k)}.\frac{(n+1)^{-(n+1)}}{n^{-n}} \tag{1}\\ &=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{(n+2)\cdots(2n+2)}{(n+1)\cdots(2n)}.\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}}{n+1} \tag{2}\\&= \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} 2(2n+1).\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}}{n+1} \tag{3} \\&= \frac{4}{e}\end{align}$

**2nd Approach:**

Write $\displaystyle a_n = \left(\binom{2n}{n}\frac{n!}{n^n}\right)^{1/n}$

Using the identity $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}^2 = \binom{2n}{n}$ we make an application of Cauchy-Schwarz Ineqality

$$\displaystyle (n+1)\binom{2n}{n} = \left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} 1^2\right)\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}^2\right) \ge \left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}\right)^2 = 4^n$$

Thus, $\displaystyle \frac{4^n}{n+1} \le \binom{2n}{n} \le 4^n \implies \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{4}{\sqrt[n]{n+1}}  = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \binom{2n}{n}^{1/n} = 4$ (form, squeeze theorem).

Since, [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n} = e^{-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28476/finding-the-limit-of-frac-n-sqrtnn?lq=1) we get $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = \frac{4}{e}$

Comment: Can you please elaborate bit more about last step

Comment: @godonichia in the last step I used $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} = e$.

Comment: No from 4th last to 3rd last

Comment: @godonichia I edited ! if its not clear yet please indicate which line I need to elaborate on ! :)

Comment: In 1st step from where did the term after product came from

Comment: @godonichia those are the denominators in the product $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{n+k+1}{n+1}$ and $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n+k}{n}$ .. there are $n+1$-terms in the numerator product thus $(n+1)^{-(n+1)}$ and $n$-terms in the denominator product hence $n^{-n}$

Comment: @godonichia welcome :) I added another approach ! ^^

Answer (score 17):

Consider that $\ln a_n$ is a sequence of Riemann sums for the function $f(x) = \ln(1 + x)$ over the interval $[0,1]$. Thus $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln a_n = \int_0^1 \ln(1 + x)\, dx = (1 + x)\ln(1 + x) - (1 + x)|_{x = 0}^1 = 2\ln(2) - 1$$ Now you can find $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ by exponentiation.

Comment: Can it be done using cauchy theorem of sequences .thanks

Comment: It can be done with Cauchy's second theorem, but I don't think it can be done with the first theorem.