# Converge the sequence $\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) \left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac{n}{n}\right)\right)^{1/n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does this series converge or diverge?

$$
\left[\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)\right]^{\frac{1}{n}}
$$

Comment: Can you think of a way to do this with Riemann sums?

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071053/to-evaluate-limit-of-sequence/1071104#1071104)'s another way of evaluating it without using Reimann Sums.

Comment: To evaluate the limit, see the link above; it has been asked before. Now, if you only need to check whether it converges or not, but not where, you can start by observeing that it is definitely bounded by $1$ and $2$. Can you say anything about its monotonicity?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** This sequence is, up to an exponential, equivalent to:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right) =\int_{1}^2\cdots\cdots$$

(use Riemann sums)

Comment: It looks like you applied the natural logarithm (and its rules) to the above expression to end up with a Riemann sum. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes this correct