# Limit of sequence $[\frac{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+n)}{n^n}]^{1/n}$ using Cauchy theorem

Tags: real-analysis, limits, radicals

I want to find the limit of following sequence by using Cauchy theorem and I don't know how.

> $\displaystyle{%
> \lim_{n \to \infty}\left[%
> \left(n + 1\right)\left(n + 2\right)\cdots\left(n + n\right)
> \over
> n^{n}\right]^{1/n}}
> $

Can someone help me ?.

Comment: What is supposed to be the statement of the Cauchy theorem you are referring to?

Comment: By continuity of $\log$/$\exp$ and Riemann sums, $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)^{1/n}=\exp\int_{0}^{1}\log(1+x)\,dx = \frac{4}{e}.$$

Comment: Jack would you please solve it by using cauchy theorem on geometric mean for the sequence.

Comment: I am not aware of such theorem. By the AM-GM inequality, the limit, if existing, is $< \frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: The formula which you have used, is it general formula that can be applied to any such sequence?

Comment: If $f(x)$ is a continuous, positive and bounded function on the interval $(0,1)$, $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n} f(k/n)^{1/n}=\exp\int_{0}^{1}\log f(x)\,dx, $$ yes.

Comment: There are several theorems called [Cauchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_theorem).

Comment: You can find the same limit [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99324/how-to-prove-that-lim-frac1n-sqrtnn1n2-2n-frac4e) (see also [linked posts](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/99324)) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071053/to-evaluate-limit-of-sequence-left-left-1-frac1n-right-left-1-frac) (see also [linked posts](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1071053).

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy's second limit theorem (with $a_n > 0$)

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n ^{1/n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}. $$

In this case,

$$\begin{align} \lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\frac{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+n)}{n^n}\right]^{1/n} &=  \lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\frac{(2n)!}{n^n n!} \right]^{1/n} \\ &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)^{n+1} (n+1)!} \frac{n^n n!}{(2n)!} \\ &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)(n+1)} \frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n} \\ &=  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2+2/n)(2+1/n)}{(1+1/n)(1+1/n)} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{(1 + 1/n)^n} \\ &= \frac{4}{e}\end{align}
$$

Comment: Very nice proof. +1