# Evaluate the limit of the sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Evaluate 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{3}{n}\right)...........\left(1+\frac{n}{n}\right)\right]^\frac{1}{n}$$
I have tried to solve this problem by taking logarithm but it works for finding the limit of functions but not in the case of sequences the answer to the problem is 4/e

Comment: This has been asked many times before. Please perform a search on the site: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071053/to-evaluate-limit-of-sequence-left-left-1-frac1n-right-left-1-frac.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L$ be your limit, and take the logarithm. You get
$$
\ln L = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1n\sum_{i = 1}^n\ln\left(1+\frac in\right)
$$
where the right-hand side is an upper Darboux sum converging to the integral
$$
\int_0^1\ln(1+x)dx =\left[-x+x\ln(1+x) + \ln(1+x)\right]_{x = 0}^1 =  \ln 4 - 1
$$
So we have $\ln L = \ln 4 -1$, which means $L = e^{\ln 4 - 1} = \frac4e$

Answer (score 0):

We can write this as ((2n!)/(n!)^2)^(1/n) which can be then simplified by using simple limit formula to get 4/e when n tends to infinity.